# Não consigo escrever uma contagem de números específicos dentro de uma lista

Tags: python-3.x

Olá, boa tarde a todos. Sou estudante na linguagem Python e estou com dificuldades em um exercício.

Desenvolvi o código que me retorna tranquilamente uma lista com meus números inseridos na lista, mas não consigo por exemplo, contabilizar quantas vezes o número 5 foi digitado. Alguem por favor, poderia me ajudar?

```
numeros = []
cont = 0
while True:
    num = input('Digite um número: ')
    while not num.isnumeric():
        print('Opção inválida')
        num = input('Digite um número: ')
    else:
        numeros += num
        cont += 1
    esc = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N]: ')
    while not esc.isalpha():
        print('Opção inválida.')
        esc = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N]: ')
    else:
        if esc in 'Ss':
            print('', end='')
        elif esc in 'Nn':
            break
        else:
            print('Por favor, use apenas S ou s, N ou n, tente novamente.')
            esc = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N]: ')
print(numeros)
print(numeros.count(5))
```

Se o código aparecer meio bagunçado aqui por conta da formatação do site que ainda não domino, me perdoem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi que sua lista é formada por strings. Desta forma, **você deve contar a string de 5**, ou seja contar quantas vezes aparece a string "5". Portanto, a única coisa que você tem que mexer é na última linha do seu código. Neste caso você deve substituir **5** por **"5"**.

Então o código ficaria:

```
numeros = []
cont = 0
while True:
    num = input('Digite um número: ')
    while not num.isnumeric():
        print('Opção inválida')
        num = input('Digite um número: ')
    else:
        numeros += num
        cont += 1
    esc = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N]: ')
    while not esc.isalpha():
        print('Opção inválida.')
        esc = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N]: ')
    else:
        if esc in 'Ss':
            print('', end='')
        elif esc in 'Nn':
            break
        else:
            print('Por favor, use apenas S ou s, N ou n, tente novamente.')
            esc = input('Deseja continuar?[S/N]: ')
print(numeros)
print(numeros.count('5'))
```

Agora, se sua intenção for montar uma lista de **números** e contar um valor numérico específico, você pode utilizar o seguinte código.

```
cont = 0
numeros = []
while True:
    cont += 1
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(f'Digite o {cont}º número: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Digite apenas número inteiros!')
    numeros.append(n)

    resp = input('Desejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'NS'):
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas ')
        resp = input('Desejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        print(f'A lista gerada foi: {numeros}')
        v = int(input('Desejas contar qual valor da lista? '))
        print(f'O valor "{v}" aparece {numeros.count(v)} vezes na lista!')
        break
```

Observe, que este último código monta uma lista de **números** e conta um valor **numérico** especificado pelo usuário.

Comment: Fico muito feliz pela resposta de cada um até agora, é de grande valia o que fazem nesse site. Agora posso continuar meus estudos sem precisar pular esse exercício e compreendendo melhor a lógica da promamação em python.

Answer (score 1):

Para simplificar a explicação vou gerar o mesmo problema em um código menor.

```py
#MESMO PROBLEMA EM UM CÓDIGO MENOR
numeros = list()
for i in range(5):
    num = input('Digite um número: ')
    numeros.append(num)
print(numeros)
print(numeros.count(5))
```

O que esse código faz é ler 5 entrada de dados, no caso a gente pede 5 números, mas pra facilitar a explicação e ficar mais fácil de ler eu não vou fiz testes com a entrada pra ver se é realmente um número.

O que acontece é o seguinte, a função `input()`, sempre vai retorna uma `string`. Ou seja, quando você adicionar o número na lista ele vai ser adicionado como `string` a não ser que você converta o número usando a função `int()` ou `float()`. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```py
numeros = list()
for i in range(5):
    num = input('Digite um número: ')
    numeros.append(int(num)) # int(num) -> transforma a `string` em inteiro.
print(numeros)
print(numeros.count(5))
```